# How to point a website to a server IP using host file

Tags: configuration, centos, host

I am using a partner xml feed on my website, the url is like xml.partner.com. Now they are planning to decommissioning the server and pointing the domain to new server. 
I have been told to point the host files on my server to their new server IP.

My server is CentOS Linux 6.8 with Apache/2.2.15 running

I have this on /etc/hosts

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain
>   localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
>
> 0.0.0.0     xml.partner.com

I couldn't see any changes. So not sure the above line is working.

Do I need to change anything on Apache configuration file? or restart Apache?

I am new to this, any help would be appreciated.

Note: When I ping their xml.partner.com I can see that it is pointed to the new server.  So unless they are not decommissioning the domain Should I bother about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You need to change in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. Find out the `Listen` keyword in the file.

In my case: `#Listen 12.34.56.78:80` and replace the ip `12.34.56.78` with your `new server IP address` and then restart `httpd server.`